# Removing punctuation is not working in Java with string replacement

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replaceall

So, what I'm trying to do is compile a single word list with no repeats out of 8 separate dictionary word lists. Some of the dictionaries have punctuation in them to separate the words. Below is what I have that pertains to the punctuation removal. I've tried several different solutions that I've found on stack overflow regarding regex expressions, as well as the one I've left in place in my code. For some reason, none of them are removing the punctuation from the source dictionaries. Can someone tell me what it is I've done wrong here and possibly how to fix it? I'm at a loss and had a coworker check it and he says this ought to be working as well.

```
int i = 1;
boolean checker = true;
Scanner inputWords;
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
        "/home/htarbox/Desktop/fullDictionary.txt");
String comparison, punctReplacer;

ArrayList<String> compilation = new ArrayList<String>();



while (i <9)
{
inputWords = new Scanner(new File("/home/htarbox/Desktop/"+i+".txt"));
    while(inputWords.hasNext())
    {
        punctReplacer = inputWords.next();
        punctReplacer.replaceAll("[;.:\"()!?\\t\\n]", "");
        punctReplacer.replaceAll(",", "");
        punctReplacer.replaceAll("\u201C", "");
        punctReplacer.replaceAll("\u201D", "");
        punctReplacer.replaceAll("’", "'");

        System.out.println(punctReplacer);
        compilation.add(punctReplacer);
    }
    }
inputWords.close();
}
i = 0;
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. Read the javadoc of methods you use.

Comment: I know strings are immutable, however, the replace function from my understanding is supposed to recreate the entire string.

Comment: You have to do: `punctReplacer = punctReplacer.replaceAll(...);`, as the function returns a new string.

Comment: What do you think recreate the string means?  What do you think immutable means? Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
punctReplacer.replaceAll(",", "");
```

returns a new `String` with your replacement (which you're ignoring). It *doesn't* modify the existing `String`. As such you need:

```
punctReplacer = punctReplacer.replaceAll(",", "");
```

`Strings` are immutable. Once created you can't change them, and any `String` manipulation method will return you a new `String`

Comment: Gotcha. My misunderstanding was that I thought the method worked similar to the mathematical += and automatically replaced that string with the new string rather than me having to assign it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

As strings are immutable you have to reset your variable:

```
punctReplacer = punctReplacer.replaceAll("[;.:\"()!?\\t\\n]", "");
```

(btw, immutable means that you cannot change the value once it has been set, so with String you always have to reset the variable if you want to change it)